# Add Horizontal Scroll Bar to Console

Tags: c++, scroll, console, scrollbar

I am writing a program in C++ that is outputting some text to the console. However, this text often is long, but I *need* it on one line. Instead of continuing to write on the same line, the program just goes to the next line and writes there.

Is there any way to make the program write to the same line, and add a horizontal scroll bar so that I can see it all?

For example, the following code outputs the letter a on multiple lines.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() {

    for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {

        cout << "a";

    }

}
```

Is there any way to make all of the "a"s outputted on the same line? Obviously this won't fit in the console screen. So, how can I add a horizontal scroll bar to see it all?

Comment: There may be a console setting for that

Comment: Are you using Linux, Windows, something else?

Comment: That question is OS-specific. What kind of `console` are you talking about?

Comment: I am using Windows. The console I am talking about is the console that appears when you run the program (the console where everything is outputted/printed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is operating system specific and cannot be solved using standard C++. As you have stated in a comment that you are using Windows, you need to take a look at the documentation provided by Microsoft.

Here is a list of functions to interact with the console: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions

The one you are interested in is

```
BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(
  _In_ HANDLE hConsoleOutput,
  _In_ COORD  dwSize
);
```

If you don't know what a console screen buffer is, Micrososft does a better job explaning it than I could, so here it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers)

The important part for you is, that the console screen buffer is a two-dimensional array. Change the array size, and you change the length of the row.

EDIT 0:
Here is an example code I have just written under the latest Windows 10 insider build using Visual Studio 2017 and C++.

After `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),coordinates)` has been executed, everything is on one line and there is a scrollbar. But there is a problem: This solution only works if the user does not resize the console. Once the user resizes the window, everything is as before. The problem can probably solved by digging through Microsoft's documentation. Haven't had a chance to do it yet.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (short int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        cout << "a";
    }

    cout << endl;

    _COORD coordinates;
    coordinates.X = 1000;
    coordinates.Y = 1000;

    if (0 == SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(
        GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
        coordinates
    ))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    for (short int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        cout << "b";
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The following code is not strictly needed:

```
for (short int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        cout << "b";
    }
```

Windows will reformat whatever has been printed before the reseizing of the buffer.

Comment: What things should I `#include` to enable usage of this function?

Comment: And also, can you post some code that uses this function? I am not familiar with the handles and other stuff that has to do with this, so an example would help.

Comment: Sorry that I did not write any code. I had to write it first. I am no editing my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! The example is perfect and this solves my issue. I'm marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: You might want to add something to the code: Event listening. You must ask Windows to inform you when the console has been reseized. Without that knowledge you do not no when to reaply the buffer reseize. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-winevents

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`SetConsoleScreenBufferSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolescreenbuffersize) or [`SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolescreenbufferinfoex) functions to change the size of the console buffer before writing to it.